# Iterate over csv and move repeated value to a header line

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to write a small python script that iterates over a CSV file to produce another file.

My goal is to produce Django models based on a CSV file.

But my code is not producing the correct result.

#### Example CSV input

```
field_1,field_2
patient,pat_ide
patient,pat_pat
inclusion,inc_ide
incusion,inc_pat
demographic,dem_ide
demographic,dem_pat
```

#### Expected result

```
models : patient
field pat_ide           # <- do not manage to get this line (see result below)
field pat_pat
line 1
line 2

models : inclusion
field inc_ide           # <- do not manage to get this line (see result below)
field inc_pat
line 1
line 2

models : demographic
field dem_ide           # <- do not manage to get this line (see result below)
field dem_pat
line 1
line 2
```

#### My attempt

I have written the code below, but it doesn't work: each time I iterate the values for a key, it overwrites the previous one:

```
models = set()
m = dict()
with open('redcap_ddd.csv', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)

    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    if has_header:
        next(spamreader)
    i = 0
    for row in spamreader:
        models.add(row[1])
        m[row[1]] = [row[0]]                    #<- row[0] is overwrited so only the second line is stored
        # m[row[1]] = ['pat_ide','pat_pat']     #<-- what I should be able to have 

print('import django 1')
print('import django 2')
print()
for model in models:
    print('models :',model)
    for field in m[model]:
        print('field',field)
    print('line 1')
    print('line 2')
    print()
```

#### Output generated by above script

As you can see, there consistently is one line missing from the output:

```
models : patient
field pat_pat           # <- only the second line is stored as list is reinitialized during loop
line 1
line 2

models : inclusion
field inc_pat           # <- only the second line is stored as list is reinitialized during loop
line 1
line 2

models : demographic
field dem_pat           # <- only the second line is stored as list is reinitialized during loop
line 1
line 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without storing the result in a data structure:

```
with open('redcap_ddd.csv', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    if has_header:
        next(spamreader)
    
    first = True
    for row in spamreader:
        if first:
            print(f"models : {row[0]}")
        first = not first 
        print(f"field {row[1]}")
        if first:
            print("line 1")
            print("line 2")
            print()
```

Comment: I got an error in line for: ```ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)```

Comment: That means your csv has more than 2 columns

Comment: Is this the case? Can you come back to me? If your CSV has more columns, it would be good to mention this in your question, because the example shows two columns, and I will adapt my answer accordingly.

Comment: my csv files look like this: field;form;var3;var4;var5;var6;var7;var8;var9;var10;var11;var12;var13;var14;var15;var16;var17;var18;var19

Comment: Can you please update the example in your question? If it is relevant, please make sure the expected output is in line with it, and really is what you expect. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thank it works except I have reverse row[0] and row[1] in code

Answer (score 1):

below my complete code working
it a code snippet that autogenerate models.py files for Django app based on csv files (data dictionnary)
hope this could help someone...

```
models_fields = []
models = set()
model_key = defaultdict(list)
m = defaultdict(list)

with open('redcap_ddd.csv', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)

    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    if has_header:
        next(spamreader)

    for row in spamreader:
        models.add(row[1])
        if row[3] == 'Entier' and row[18] == 'P':
            model_key[row[1]].append(row[0].lower())
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+' = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)')
        elif row[3] == 'Entier':
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.IntegerField("+str(row[4])+", null=True, blank=True)")              
        elif row[3] == 'Booleen':
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.BooleanField("+str(row[4])+", null=True, blank=True)")
        elif row[3] == 'Octet' and row[9] =='Case à cocher':
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.BooleanField("+str(row[4])+", null=True, blank=True)")
        elif row[3] == 'Octet' and row[9] =='menu déroulant':
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.IntegerField("+str(row[4])+", null=True, blank=True)")
        elif row[3] == 'Réel':
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.FloatField("+str(row[4])+", null=True, blank=True)")
        elif row[3][:6] == 'Texte' and row[18] == 'I':
            t = len(row[0])-1
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.CharField("+str(row[4])+", max_length='"+str(row[3][8:t])+"', unique=True, null=True, blank=True)")
        elif row[3][:6] == 'Texte':
            t = len(row[4])-1
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.CharField("+str(row[4])+", max_length='"+str(row[3][8:t])+"', null=True, blank=True)")
        elif row[3] == 'Date' and  row[6] == 'jj/mm/aaaa' and  row[7] == '':
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.DateField("+str(row[4])+", null=True, blank=True)")
        elif row[3] == 'Date' and  row[6] == 'jj/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss' and  row[7] == '':
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.DateTimeField("+str(row[4])+", null=True, blank=True)")
        elif row[3] == 'Date' and  row[6] == 'jj/mm/aaaa' and  row[7] == 'auto (serveur)':
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.DateField("+str(row[4])+", , null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=True)")
        elif row[3] == 'Date' and  row[6] == 'jj/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss' and  row[7] == 'auto (serveur)':
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.DateTimeField("+str(row[4])+", null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=True)")
        else:
            m[row[1]].append(str(row[0].lower())+" = models.CharField("+str(row[4])+", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)")
        
# print('m',m)
# print('m["patient"]',m["patient"])
# print('model_key',model_key)
# print('model_key["patient"][0]',model_key["patient"][0])

with open('models.txt', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as f1:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f1,delimiter=' ',quotechar='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    thewriter2 = csv.writer(f1,delimiter=' ',quotechar='',escapechar=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    print('import django 1')
    print('import django 2')
    print()
    thewriter2.writerow(['from django.db import models',])
    thewriter2.writerow(['from safedelete.models import SafeDeleteModel, SOFT_DELETE, SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE',])
    thewriter2.writerow(['from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords',])
    thewriter2.writerow(['from django.utils import timezone',])
    thewriter2.writerow(['from partial_date import PartialDateField',])
    thewriter2.writerow('')

    for model in models:
        print('models :',model)
        thewriter2.writerow(['class '+model.capitalize()+'(models.Model):',])
        thewriter2.writerow(['\t'+'""" A class to create a '+model+' instance. """',])
        thewriter2.writerow('')        

        for field in m[model]:
            print('field',field)
            thewriter.writerow(field.split(";"))
        print('line 1')
        print('line 2')
        print()
        thewriter2.writerow(['\t'+'log = HistoricalRecords()',])
        thewriter2.writerow('')
        thewriter2.writerow(['\t'+'class Meta:',])
        thewriter2.writerow(['\t\t'+'db_table = "crf_'+model[:3]+'"',])
        thewriter2.writerow(['\t\t'+'verbose_name_plural = '+model.capitalize()+'s',])
        thewriter2.writerow(['\t\t'+'ordering = ["'+model_key[model][0]+'"]',])
        thewriter2.writerow('')
        thewriter2.writerow(['\t'+'def __str__(self):',])
        thewriter2.writerow(['\t\t'+'return f"{self.'+model_key[model][0]+'}"',])
        thewriter2.writerow('')
        thewriter2.writerow('')
```